# Wordpress: get resized URL of the custom-cropped thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I would like to display the manually-cropped thumbnail in the blog archive page. If I use this code, the original image is scaled and resized and not the manually cropped/sized thumbnail, which in my case chops off the head of the person in the picture:

```
//functions.php
add_image_size( 'archive-thumbnail', 220, 150, true );   
set_post_thumbnail_size( 220, 150 );
//archive.php 
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(),'archive-thumbnail');
```

If I use `the_post_thumbnail(array(220,150));` , I get 150px high "square-ish" image scaled down, again, based on the original image and not the manually-cropped thumbnail.
The closest to what I want is this:

```
$url=wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()));
```

I get the manually cropped image, but it is scaled incorrectly - it is 150px wide and not tall.
So my question: how do I get the scaled URL of the manually cropped media thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to get the resized image - the function`wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()` is a shortcut to get the thumbnail size.

```
$post_id  = get_the_ID();
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$img_src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'archive-thumbnail' );
```

Comment: What is the name of the image generated by the code aboce and the cropped one you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you edit code related to thumbnails after thumbnails have already been created, you need to regenerate them. Try using the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.